# Processing Key events in a Textbox using Japanese IME VB.net

Tags: vb.net, ime

I'm using a textbox that has the IME enabled for Japanese.

Since this allows you to type in Roman characters and then select from a list of kanji or kana, the actual text isn't entered into the textbox until you've made a selection by hitting the enter key.

I want to be able to process non-text keys, such as the Left and Right arrow, Add, Subtract, but the KeyUp/Down events all treat the key which is pressed as ProcessCommandKey with a value of 229. It appears the IME has all the control over the input. I don't see any further data from the KeyEventArgs.

How can I check a key's ACTUAL value (Left, Right, etc.) from the event when the IME is active?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you are in search of alternatives (if I well understand) of KeyUp/ KeyDown Event handler this one might be a way to consider. In practice you can extend the `TextBox` Class then Override the `WndProc` Method.
You can listen for WM_KEYUP messages then get the parameter that indetify the key which is pressed. The code below shows a base from which someone can start the improve it:

```
   Private Class MyTextBox
        Inherits TextBox

        Dim H As String = "&H"
        Private WM_KEYUP As Integer = CInt(H & "0x101")

        Private VK_RIGHT As Integer = CInt(H & "0x27")
        Private VK_LEFT As Integer = CInt(H & "0x25")
        Private VK_ADD As Integer = CInt(H & "0x6B")
        Private VK_SUBTRACT As Integer = CInt(H & "0x6D")

        Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)

            If m.Msg.Equals(WM_KEYUP) Then
                Select Case m.WParam.ToInt32
                    Case VK_RIGHT
                        Debug.WriteLine("RIGHT ARROW pressed")

                    Case VK_LEFT
                        Debug.WriteLine("LEFT ARROW pressed")

                    Case VK_ADD
                        Debug.WriteLine("+ pressed")

                    Case VK_SUBTRACT
                        Debug.WriteLine("- pressed")

                End Select
            End If
            MyBase.WndProc(m)
        End Sub

    End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a rather offbeat solution to this which I'm guessing may not work on all systems, but what I did is to check the System.Char value in the KeyUp event.

It seems that Direction Keys are treated as "Punctuation," so System.Char.IsPunctuation returns true

```
    Dim c As Char = ChrW(e.KeyCode)

    Select Case True
        Case System.Char.IsPunctuation(c)
            Select Case e.KeyCode
                  Case Keys.Left
                       'Code here
            End select
    End Select
```

Note this only occurs when the Textbox is in IME mode.

(Also the Function Keys return the values of p-z)